# HttpRequest with angular

Tags: asp.net, angular

I am using Angular v5 and I am trying to do a simple request to my api endpoint in .net core web api in order to retrieve the data.

My ts code:

```
getOtherData<T>(countryCode: string, zip: string): Observable<any> {
    const endpointUrl = `${this.countrysUrl}/get_other_data`;
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .append('countryCode', countryCode)
        .append('zip', zip);
    const headers = this.getRequestHeaders().headers

    return this.http.get<T>(endpointUrl, {headers: headers, params: params})
        .catch(error => {
            return this.handleError(error, () => this.getOtherData(countryCode, zip));
        });
}
```

My api endpoint:

```
/// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="countryCode"></param>
    /// <param name="zip"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet("get_other_data")]
    public IActionResult GetOtherData(string countryCode, string zip)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = _repository.GetOtherData(countryCode, zip);
            if (item != null)
            {
                return Ok(item);
            }

            return NotFound(zip);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            LogError($"Error in Get by id {zip} of{typeof(ClassRoom)} Error: {ex.Message}, Stack: {ex.StackTrace}", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: I'm kindly returning the question to you : What is wrong ? do you have any error ? incorrect behavior ? Please give details, as we probably cannot reproduce it as is.

Comment: can you open chrome devTools, go to network and copy the response&request?

Comment: If you don't have any request firing, make sure you subscribe to your Observable somewhere (like : `getOtherData('xx', 'yy').subscribe((result) => { console.log(result); }, (error) => { console.error(error); });`

Comment: also, why do you have a `<T>` ? it is probably useless, you should remove them as far as I understand.

Comment: Kindly let us know what problem are you facing?

Comment: I am getting network error

Comment: And yes, i am subscribed to my Observable: `this.countryService.getOtherData(this.editedFacility.country, this.editedFacility.postalCode).subscribe(results => this.onCountryGetOtherDataLoadSuccessful(results[0], results[1]),
        error => this.onCountryGetOtherDataLoadFailed(error))`

Comment: What type of network error? And is this network error thrown on client or on server?

Comment: Was or server, it's fixed now, but in trying to return to client a tuple(province, state) and i do not know how handle this response on angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i have a server error so the network error was a `500`. And then i wanted to return a tuple and i did not know how to handle the response.

I already fix it whit that.

```
this.countryService.getOtherData(this.editedFacility.country, this.editedFacility.postalCode).subscribe(results => this.onCountryGetOtherDataLoadSuccessful(results),
    error => this.onCountryGetOtherDataLoadFailed(error));
```

and the method definition:

```
onCountryGetOtherDataLoadSuccessful(results: any){
this.alertService.stopLoadingMessage();

this.editedFacility.province = results.item1;
this.editedFacility.municipality = results.item2;
```

}